# Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't work with Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server object

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have a connection string to the *remote* MS SQL server and try to query this server using Invoke-SqlCmd cmdlet.
Here is the script:

```
$ConnectionString = "data source=sqldev;initial catalog=test;User Id=dev;Password=mypassword;"

.\LoadSqlServerSMO.ps1 #this just loads SMO modules

$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
$connection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($sqlConnection)
$serverObject = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server($connection)

$q1 = "select * from currency"
```

## this command perfectly works:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -Query $q1 `
  -ServerInstance "sqldev" -Database "test"  -Username "dev" -Password "mypassword" `
  -ConnectionTimeout 3 -OutputSqlErrors $true -QueryTimeout 3 -SuppressProviderContextWarning -IgnoreProviderContext
```

## this command fails:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -Query $q1 `
-ServerInstance $serverObject `
-ConnectionTimeout 3 -OutputSqlErrors $true -QueryTimeout 3 -SuppressProviderContextWarning -IgnoreProviderContext

invoke-sqlcmd : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance
At Untitled3.ps1:22 char:14
+ $sqlResult = invoke-sqlcmd -Query $q1 `
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotGetServerInstance,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Looks, like it's a bug in powershell... or am I doing something wrong?

Just in case, here is $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17090
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

And $serverObject is populated, not-null object, connection exist, username/password is OK:

$serverObject.Information | fl *
gives the following:

```
BuildClrVersionString       : v4.0.30319
BuildNumber                 : 5058
Collation                   : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CollationID                 : 872468488
ComparisonStyle             : 196609
ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS : DEV-DB1
Edition                     : Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
ErrorLogPath                : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log
FullyQualifiedNetName       : dev-db1.dev.mydomain.local
IsCaseSensitive             : False
IsClustered                 : False
IsFullTextInstalled         : False
IsHadrEnabled               : True
IsSingleUser                : False
IsXTPSupported              : False
Language                    : English (United States)
MasterDBLogPath             : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
MasterDBPath                : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
MaxPrecision                : 38
NetName                     : DEV-DB1
OSVersion                   : 6.2 (9200)
PhysicalMemory              : 31250
Platform                    : NT x64
Processors                  : 4
Product                     : Microsoft SQL Server
ProductLevel                : SP2
ResourceLastUpdateDateTime  : 5/14/2014 18:34:17
ResourceVersionString       : 11.00.5058
RootDirectory               : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL
SqlCharSet                  : 1
SqlCharSetName              : iso_1
SqlSortOrder                : 52
SqlSortOrderName            : nocase_iso
VersionMajor                : 11
VersionMinor                : 0
VersionString               : 11.0.5058.0
Parent                      : [sqldev]
Version                     : 11.0.5058
EngineEdition               : EnterpriseOrDeveloper
ResourceVersion             : 11.0.5058
BuildClrVersion             : 4.0.30319
Urn                         : Server[@Name='DEV-DB1']/Information
Properties                  : {...properties here...}
UserData                    :
State                       : Existing
```

With tracing turned on:

```
trace-command -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost -Expression {invoke-sqlcmd -Query $q1 -ServerInstance $serverObject -ConnectionTimeout 3 -OutputSqlErrors $true -QueryTimeout 3 -SuppressProviderContextWarning -IgnoreProviderContext}


DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Invoke-Sqlcmd]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [select * from currency] to parameter [Query]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata:
[System.Management.Automation.ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [select * from currency] to param [Query] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [[sqldev]] to parameter [ServerInstance]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [[sqldev]] to param [ServerInstance] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [3] to parameter [ConnectionTimeout]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Int32]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [3] to param [ConnectionTimeout] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [OutputSqlErrors]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Boolean]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [OutputSqlErrors] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [3] to parameter [QueryTimeout]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Int32]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [3] to param [QueryTimeout] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [SuppressProviderContextWarning]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [SuppressProviderContextWarning] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [IgnoreProviderContext]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [IgnoreProviderContext] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Invoke-Sqlcmd]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Invoke-Sqlcmd]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [out-lineoutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [format-default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata:
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
invoke-sqlcmd : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ServerInstance
At C:\code\platform\DrWorkerService\src\PowershellScripts\Untitled3.ps1:26 char:59
+ trace-command -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost -Expression {invoke-sqlcmd -Query $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotGetServerInstance,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Comment: ServerInstance does not expect/accept an object to be passed but the string containing the Server\instance.

Comment: get-help invoke-sqlcmd -parameter serverinstance
gives you the following:

-ServerInstance <psobject>
A character string or SMO server object specifying the name of an instance of the Database Engine. For default instances, only specify the computer name: "MyComputer". For named instances, use the format "ComputerName\InstanceName".